# Difference between redefining self.included and passing block to included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the difference between

```
module A
  def self.included(klass)
    puts klass
  end
end
```

and

```
module A
  include ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    puts self
  end
end
```

Which one is a better and which one to use when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both snippets produce the same result. However, there is a small but important difference.

The first code is pure Ruby. It means it will work without any dependency.

The second piece of code depends on ActiveSupport that is an external dependency. If you want to use it you need to include the gem in your project. In a Rails application, there is almost no overhead because the application already depends on ActiveSupport. But in a non-Rails application, it may not be convenient.

Moreover, `ActiveSupport::Concern` does a lot more than simply adding some syntactic sugar for the Ruby included hook. In fact, the primary scope of such module was to manage multiple dependencies between modules.

In the Rails codebase it's very common to define small piece of features into separate modules. A good example is `ActiveSupport` itself. However, you may have that the feature `A` may require some feature defined in the module `B`, so if you include `B` in your code, then the module should make sure to require and mix also `A`, otherwise your code will crash.

It also implements a very common pattern based on the included hook: class-level extensions. The following Ruby code

```
module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def bar
      "bar"
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include A
end

Foo.bar
# => "bar"
```

becomes

```
module A
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def bar
      "bar"
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include A
end

Foo.bar
# => "bar"
```

My personal advice is to avoid using the `ActiveSupport::Concern` if

- You don't need to use its advanced features
- The code you are writing, can be easily written with a few code with no dependency on `Concern`
- The app does not already include `ActiveSupport` as dependency

Answer (score -1):

In your second piece of code, `included` is called once during when `A` is defined. It does not do anything unless you had defined `included` to do something. The block passed to `included` would have no effect unless you had overwritten `included` to take a block and do something with it. In short, your second piece of code does not make sense.

Comment: But there is a method in activesupport::concern which we may directly use

Comment: Downvoted because, as mentioned in the last comment, this overrides a method explicitly included in the line above it.
It makes perfect sense, so this is a non-answer, as you're just getting confused. If you don't understand something, please don't add an answer for it stating that